# Error in stored procedure when populating the values through sequence

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

One of the `procedure` when executed gets failed during the execution of the below statement. Please. let me know on how to fix the below error.

Error :

> Msg 11719, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SeedDimProduct, Line 69 [Batch Start Line 2]
>   NEXT VALUE FOR function is not allowed in check constraints, default objects, computed columns, views, user-defined functions, user-defined aggregates, user-defined table types, sub-queries, common table expressions, derived tables or return statements.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.DimProduct
    (
        [ProductKey] 
        ,[ProductCode]
        ,[ProductCode]
        ,[ProductName]
        ,[ProductWaterfallGroupKey]
        ,[InsertExecutionID]
        ,[UpdateExecutionID]
        ,[DisplayOrder]
    )
    select distinct * 
    from (SELECT    
     NEXT VALUE FOR DBO.SQ_WATERFALL_PROD, 
     ProductCode             =   c.ResourceNo
    ,ProductCode      =   c.ProductID
    ,ProductName                =   p.[Product_NM]
    ,w.ProductWaterfallgroupkey
    ,InsertExecutionID          =   0
    ,UpdateExecutionID          =   0
    ,DisplayOrder               =   0
FROM targit_Updated.[dbo].[FS_ContractTypeProduct_D] c
LEFT JOIN [DWSF].[dbo].[SF_Product_D] p ON c.ProductID = p.[Product_ID] COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
 JOIN #ProdWaterfallGrouping w on w.ReportingGroup= p.Reporting_Group_DSC) as x
```

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be in subquery, so move it out:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.DimProduct
    (
        [ProductKey] 
        ,[ProductCode]
        ,[ProductCode]
        ,[ProductName]
        ,[ProductWaterfallGroupKey]
        ,[InsertExecutionID]
        ,[UpdateExecutionID]
        ,[DisplayOrder]
    )
    select NEXT VALUE FOR DBO.SQ_WATERFALL_PROD, x.*
    from (
    select distinct * 
     ProductCode             =   c.ResourceNo
    ,ProductCode      =   c.ProductID
    ,ProductName                =   p.[Product_NM]
    ,w.ProductWaterfallgroupkey
    ,InsertExecutionID          =   0
    ,UpdateExecutionID          =   0
    ,DisplayOrder               =   0
FROM targit_Updated.[dbo].[FS_ContractTypeProduct_D] c
LEFT JOIN [DWSF].[dbo].[SF_Product_D] p ON c.ProductID = p.[Product_ID] COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
 JOIN #ProdWaterfallGrouping w on w.ReportingGroup= p.Reporting_Group_DSC) as x
```